# Using dGPU only for acceleration tasks?

Tags: nvidia, gpu

I'm looking at getting a new laptop for work/school and I'm in a bit of a predicament. I've been looking at the Lenovo X1 Extreme (intel integrated graphics + gtx 1050ti), but I've heard that auto switching GPUs is still quite bad on Linux in comparison to Windows.

Now I don't need a GPU for much - just light gaming (which I'd do in Windows anyways), and for tasks that benefit from GPU acceleration (some programming, and programs like Blender, which I want to solely do in Linux). I would still like good battery life though, so always using the dGPU in Linux isn't an option.

So my question is - can I use integrated graphics in Ubuntu as my main GPU, yet still get the option to use the dGPU for acceleration tasks? If so is there some special way to do so? Are there distros that handle GPU switching much better than Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer: No (but it's the same in Windows). Laptops with hybrid graphics aren't the same as desktops with with multiple graphics.

Comment: Linux doesn't have per application GPU setting. Just turn dGPU off and use iGPU when on battery in Linux.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The only difference is Windows can switch to the iGPU without rebooting. It's not like different apps can use different GPUs at the same time (that would defeat the power saving purpose anyway and by a lot). What happens is if there's at least one app requesting the "high performance" (dGPU) profile Windows switches to the dGPU an conversely if there's none it'll stay with or switch back tothe iGPU. The only difference is Windows can do it without rebooting.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia As far as Optimus laptops are concerned in Windows you can specify which apps will use dedicated GPU and which use integrated GPU whilst both GPUs are concurrently running. This is what I was referring too because in Linux it is all of one `prime-select nvidia` or all of the other `prime-select intel`. The fact of the matter is unless you are gaming, most Linux users are well served by the integrated GPU. The exception may be 4K video content but I'm just starting with that myself. Perhaps you should post an answer and ping me and I'll upvote it :)

Comment: That's not what I've been told (and that doesn't make sense). How come they can can work concurrently to draw the same desktop? And what power saving you'd get by having two devices consuming energy when only one, the dGPU, is enough for all tasks? With (newer) desktops with multi-monitor feature is different: All cards can be used at the same time, either drawing different desktops (monitors) or one or more used only for data processing (e.g. Tensorflow).

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I don't use Windows often but if I recall correctly you can apply overrides on an App by App basis and say if it will use Intel CPU or nVidia. I can't speak about your desktop references because all my nVidia experiences have been on laptops. One key point to remember is even if you are using Intel iGPU your laptop may still have nVidia powered up even if it's still sitting idle it might be using 5 watts instead of the customary 30 or 40 watts or whatever. All my laptops are plugged in 24/7 so I don't worry. "Data Processing" is old school BTW. Did you use punch cards too?

Comment: "Data processing" is a term I've learn from my uncle and yes, he's old(ish)... An operative word to remember is "switchable" and one point to remember is the iGPU is usually the default and the dGPU is "on demand". From https://www.pcworld.com/article/2944964/how-to-use-nvidia-optimus-to-switch-active-gpus-and-save-power-on-linux-laptops.html *... use a technology called Nvidia Optimus to intelligently **switch between the two**. Intel’s CPU-integrated graphics power the desktop for lower power usage, while Nvidia’s more capable GeForce graphics **kick into gear** when you need them. >>>

Comment: There's no way Nvidia working alone for everything consumes more than Nvidia+Intel working concurrently no matter how low powered Intel is. And, again, not even technically possible to have two GPUs drawing different apps in the same desktops(s), same ports. The profiles by app in Windows allows overriding what would be the default behavior managed by the (Nvidia's) driver, forcing one app to high performance or vice-versa. But as long as there's a process running that requests high performance, the dGPU kicks in and that one only instead of the iGPU, not concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. At the moment there is no such functionality in the official nvidia driver for linux to offload some applications on the gpu and the rest uses the integrated graphics. You can, however switch between the graphics cards with prime-select. But you have to log out and log into the system which is not feasible. There is an old project called "bumblebee" which also made some changes to nvidia drivers to allow for such a "render offloading" but it doesn't seem quite active anymore.

Recently I have looked into the topic and it seems that nvidia is finally working on a solution to allow "render offloading" of applications in linux. There was some license issues in the past but they have now been resolved.

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GLXVND-Offload-Improve-1.21

This feature may be implemented in the next iterations of the driver versions. So you should be fine by then.

Also see this thread where Aaron Plattner one of the lead devs from Nvidia gives some updates on the current status

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/957981/linux/prime-render-offloading-on-nvidia-optimus/3